# How to create a self-signed development certificate good for multiple origins

Tags: angular, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am developing an Angular application on a Fedora box and would like to be able to serve the development build in such a way that I can use one node for developing and serving and others for browsing, testing and viewing etc.

I have created a self-signed cert which works perfectly when browsing to 'localhost:4200' but fails when browsing to 'mydomain:4200' (ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).

Ideally I would like a cert that can support both, but a self-signed development certificate good for 'mydomain' will suffice.

How might this be achieved using OpenSSL?